# Reversing a sub-list inside a linked list and re-connecting original head

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

I'm working on a reverse-linked list problem where you reverse a sub-list within the Linked-list structure. The sublist is defined with `left` and `right` which is the portion you must reverse. When working with smaller sized Linked Lists (size 2) it works fine but when working with 5 elements or so, it begins to fail. This is because (as seen in the example) I do not quite understand how to maintain the original head and connect to my now reversed sub-list. I have tried `head->next = prev;` but this did not work and resulted in nullptr memory access error.

Quite new to this data structure and would appreciate any insight into how I might go about solving the issue.

```
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
    ListNode* dummy = new ListNode(0, head);
    ListNode* prev = nullptr;
    ListNode* current = head;
    int counter = 1;
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        if (counter == left)
        {
            ListNode* lastKnownParent = current;
            ListNode* n = nullptr;
            while (counter <= right)
            {
                n = current->next;
                current->next = prev;
                prev = current;
                current = n;
                counter++;
            }
            lastKnownParent->next = current;
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    dummy->next->next = current;
    dummy->next = prev;
   
    return dummy->next;
    
}
```

Success with smaller sized:
`input: [3,5] left = 1, right = 2: Output: [5,3]`

Fail with larger size:
`input: [1,2,3,4,5] left = 2, right = 4: Output: [2,4,3,2,5]`

Comment: Pay attention to that indices in C++ start from 0.

Comment: I suggest you take a couple of steps back and restart by *ignoring* the code you have and the computer. Instead bring out a pencil and some paper. Draw a list, using (labeled) boxes for the nodes, and arrows for the links and other pointers. Then try to figure out a way to do it all on paper, erasing and redrawing the arrows to make things work. Once it all works on paper you start to write some code, but only a *little* piece of code that can be built (with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors) and tested in isolation.

Comment: Make a drawing of a linked list (nodes and links) and reason about how you would do it on paper, then work that out in code. Start a debugger and single step through your code and verify it makes the same steps you've on paper. Learning how to use a debugger is a skill you will need to have anyway :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Amazing similarity in advice here.  Maybe we're on to something here :)

Comment: I also recommend you do it in several distinct parts. Like for example one part (function) to do the reversing, and one part (function) to find the specified nodes, and one part (function) to "split" and "reinsert" the reversed "sub-list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- The lines at the bottom of your function are not good. They hard-code that some change needs to happen at the first two nodes of the list, but this makes no sense when for example the reversal has to take place between nodes 4 and 6. So those two lines should be removed:

  ```
  dummy->next->next = current;
  dummy->next = prev;
  ```
- The node that *precedes* `lastKnownParent` will have to get its `next` pointer updated, but the problem is that there is no direct reference anymore to that node. The statements I quoted above were probably meant to reach that node, but it has to be done relative to the `left` position.

To illustrate what goes wrong, look at this visualisation when we have a list of 8 nodes and the two given positions are `left=4` and `right=6`:

When reaching `left` and entering the loop, we get this state:

```
                            lastKnownParent
dummy    head                   current   n
  ↓       ↓                       ↓       ↓ 
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   
│ 0 ├──►│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 3 ├──►│ 4 ├──►│ 5 ├──►│ 6 ├──►│ 7 ├──►│ 8 │
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘
                          
                          prev == nulltptr
```

When reaching `right`, the loop makes one more iteration and then the loop exits, resulting in this state:

```
dummy    head               lastKnownParent     prev    current   n
  ↓       ↓                       ↓               ↓       ↓       ↓
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 0 ├──►│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 3 ├──►│ 4 │◄──┤ 5 │◄──┤ 6 │   │ 7 ├──►│ 8 │
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └─┬─┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘
                                  ▼
                                nullptr
```

Your code then correctly sets the `next` pointer of the node with value 4 (`lastKnownParent`):

```
dummy    head               lastKnownParent     prev    current   n
  ↓       ↓                       ↓               ↓       ↓       ↓
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 0 ├──►│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 3 ├──►│ 4 │◄──┤ 5 │◄──┤ 6 │   │ 7 ├──►│ 8 │
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └─┬─┘   └───┘   └───┘   └─▲─┘   └───┘
                                  └───────────────────────┘
```

But there is one thing missing. The link from node 3 to node 6 still needs to be made. This is something you *seem* to have tried at the very end of your function, but you cannot assume that it is always `dummy->next->next` that needs to change. This depends on `left`, or in other words, it depends on `lastKnownParent`. The problem is that `lastKnownParent` points to the successor of the node that needs this update. So, make `lastKnownParent` to point to the *predecessor* instead, at the time it is initialised. Then you can make both updates (first updating node 4, then node 3). Then it would look like this:

```
dummy    head       lastKnownParent             prev    current   n
  ↓       ↓              ↓┌──────────────────────┐↓       ↓       ↓
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌─┴─┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌▼──┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ 0 ├──►│ 1 ├──►│ 2 ├──►│ 3 │   │ 4 │◄──┤ 5 │◄──┤ 6 │   │ 7 ├──►│ 8 │
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └─┬─┘   └───┘   └───┘   └─▲─┘   └───┘
                                  └───────────────────────┘
```

To make it possible to set `lastKnownParent` one node earlier, you could for instance have `prev` follow behind `current` even in the first iterations -- when `left` is not yet encountered.

Here is the corrected code, with comments where something changed:

```
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
    ListNode* dummy = new ListNode(0, head);
    ListNode* prev = dummy; // prev follows behind current
    ListNode* current = head;
    int counter = 1;
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        if (counter == left)
        {
            ListNode* lastKnownParent = prev; // one node earlier
            ListNode* n = nullptr;
            while (counter <= right)
            {

                n = current->next;
                current->next = prev;
                prev = current;
                current = n;
                counter++;
            }
            // lastKnownParent is now one node earlier than in your code
            lastKnownParent->next->next = current;
            lastKnownParent->next = prev; // now the mutation is complete...
            break; // ... so we don't need to iterate the remaining nodes.
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            prev = current; // prev follows behind current
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    // Removed two statements here
    return dummy->next;
}
```

### Further improvements

This code assumes that the given positions are valid. You may want to improve on this and determine what should happen when one or both are out of range, or `right` is less than `left`.

You may also want to think of more elegant ways to solve this challenge. For instance, you could create functions that can:

- inverse a complete list
- split a list at a certain position into two smaller lists.
- concatenate smaller lists into one

This may lead to code that is more readable.

Comment: Thank you so so much for this incredibly detailed explanation. This has helped me understand so much! I genuinely cannot thank you enough!